# Changing column order in DataTable bound to DataGridView does not reflect in the view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

When the application is run, the `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataTable`. Later I add more columns to the `DataTable` programmatically and it is reflected in the underlying data - i.e. the column Ordinals are as they should be. However this is not reflected in the `DataGridView`. Instead columns are appended onto the originally generated set.

This example demonstrates,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataTable data = new DataTable();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            this.data.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataColumn foo = new DataColumn();
        this.data.Columns.Add(foo);
        foo.SetOrdinal(0);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn tmpCol in this.data.Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", tmpCol.ColumnName, tmpCol.Ordinal);
        }
    }
}
```

Button 1 generates the columns, button 2 adds a column and sets the ordinal to 0 so it should be first in the grid, button 3 displays the ordinals of the columns and shows they are how they should be in the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is just how `DataGridView` works; with auto-generate columns enabled, extra (unmapped) columns are appended to the end. You can unbind and re-bind to fix it; set the DataSource to null and back to the table:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and solved it with the DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex property.

```
dgvData.Columns["COLUMN_NAME"].DisplayIndex = 0;  // will move your custom column to first position
```

Comment: The solution above gives more refined control after dynamically binding the dgv to a binding data source:


            BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();


            dgvConciseView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

            bindingSource.DataSource = new myDataClass() { T = 5, TR = 5, K = 0, t = 3, N = 3600 };

            dgvConciseView.DataSource = bindingSource;

            dgvConciseView.Columns["T"].DisplayIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

See Koryu's answer below!  The solution below gives more refined control after dynamically binding the dgv to a binding data source:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
dgvData.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
bindingSource.DataSource = new myDataClass() { T = 5, TR = 5, K = 0, t = 3, N = 3600 };
dgvData.DataSource = bindingSource;
dgvData.Columns["T"].DisplayIndex = 0;    //******* Koryu's answer below
```