# Force WPF DataGrid to regenerate itself

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, auto-generate

I have a custom control which inherits from `DataGrid` and is basically a 2D `DataGrid` (accepts an `ItemsSource` with two dimensions, such as `double[,]` ).

I added a specific `DependencyProperty` which is `ColumnHeaders` and `RowHeaders` so I can define them.

Here is how it works right now:

- I bind a 2D `ItemsSource` to the `DataGrid`
- A wrapper method will take this source to transform it to a classic `IEnumerable` bindable to the actual datagrid's `ItemsSource`
- Each row / column auto-generated is done using the events `AutoGeneratingColumn` & `AutoGeneratingRow` in order to define their header

**The problem here:**

When I initialize the `DataGrid`, everything works fine.

After that, one of the use-cases of my application defines that only the column headers can change (by modifying the `DependencyProperty` `ColumnHeaders`

And, whatever I do here, the `DataGrid` won't re-autogenerate its columns (and therefore, headers won't be changed in any way).

So, is there a way to ask the `DataGrid` something like "Hey, I want you to restart from scratch and regenerate your columns" ? Because for now, I can't reach the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event, and calling a method such as `InvalidateVisual` will just redraw the grid (and not regenerate columns).

Any ideas here?

I'm not sure that we need some code but... I'll put some so nobody asks for it :D

```
    /// <summary>
    /// IList of String containing column headers
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnHeaders",
                                    typeof(IEnumerable),
                                    typeof(FormattedDataGrid2D),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(HeadersChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler called when the binding on ItemsSource2D changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void ItemsSource2DPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FormattedDataGrid2D @this = source as FormattedDataGrid2D;
        @this.OnItemsSource2DChanged(e.OldValue as IEnumerable, e.NewValue as IEnumerable);
    }

        // (in the constructor)
        AutoGeneratingColumn += new EventHandler<DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs>(DataGrid2D_AutoGeneratingColumn);

    void DataGrid2D_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn column = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        column.Header = (ColumnHeaders == null) ? columnIndex++ : (ColumnHeaders as IList)[columnIndex++]; //Header will be the defined header OR the column number
        column.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
        Binding binding = column.Binding as Binding;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(binding.Path.Path + ".Value"); // Workaround to get a good value to display, do not take care of that
    }
```

Comment: why not try resetting the ItemsSource property

Comment: It actually works (and I can't believe I haven't thought about that earlier -__- ), but is there any "smarter" way to do that?

Comment: @Damascus Have you found a smarter way than unsetting and setting itemssource? I'm looking for that as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reset your ItemsSource and it should redraw your DataGrid

```
void ResetDataGrid()
{
    var temp = myDataGrid.ItemsSource;
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = temp;
}
```

You might also be able to refresh the binding, but I haven't tested it to see if this will actually regenerate the DataGrid:

```
void ResetDataGrid()
{
    myDataGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
Refreshing won't work as WPF will first automatically check if the bound property has actually changed (which is not the case)
Reseting itemssource works fine, but I was wondering if there isn't any "more elegant" solution?

Answer (score 4):

Toggling AutogeneratedColumns off and then on will cause the columns to be automatically generated again.

```
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Comment: I have a similar scenario to the OP and this solution worked better than the other solution. For some reason, directly messing with the ItemsSource caused auto-generation not to work.